# Table...aligning cells and input boxes

Tags: html, nested, html-table, alignment, cell

I am creating 1 of 3 nested tables within the `<form>` tag in my HTML document. I inserted input fields to create the text boxes to the right of the text. That all works my only problem is that the following cells: "First Name, Last Name, Address, City, State, Zip Code, and County" are not directly under one another in such a way as to keep the cells aligned and the text boxes aligned. How do I align each section? I hope I am explaining this well if not please ask for further clarification. Any help on this minor problem would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code so far so you can see what I did:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<head>
<img src="j0182695_downsized.jpg" alt="Oatmeal Raisin cookies" style="float: left" >

</head>


<body background="back-225.gif">
<h1 style="text-align: center; color: red; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Cookies</h1>

<table width="500" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><a href="about.htm">About Us</a></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="mailto:cookiemaster@example.com">Contact Us</a></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="orderform.htm">Place an Order</a></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="recipe.htm">Sample Recipe</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form name="Web Order Form" id="Web Order Form">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" width="65%">
    <tr>
        <td>Personal Information</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name:
        <input name="fname" id="fname" size="30" type="text"   />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name:
        <input name="lname" id="lname" size="30" type="text"  />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address:
        <input name="address" id="address" size="30" type="text"  />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City:
        <input name="city" id="city" size="35" type="text"  />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>State:
        <input name="state" id="state" size="3" type="text"  />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zip Code:
        <input name="zip" id="zip" size="10" type="text"  />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Country:
        <input name="country" id="country" size="10" type="text"  />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: This is not programming related.  This question may be better suited to http://doctype.com/

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton: Sorry I thought it was since it's dealing with HTML. I will check out the site you mentioned. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I hope you like Doctype!

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton There are 12038 questions tagged as HTML on SO. I am betting quite a few of them are about layout.

Comment: @Ashley You need to decide if you are going to write XHTML or HTML (and find out the differences between them). As I am not that smart, I find it easier to stick with HTML and use a `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` to trigger standards compliant mode (see http://www.dustindiaz.com/skinny-on-doctypes/ ) As for your form layout, make sure that labels for form inputs are labeled as `<label>`s. Nested tables seem straightforward at first but get really nasty quick. See http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms/ for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the input boxes in another cell like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>First Name:</td>
    <td><input name="fname" id="fname" size="30" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
```

If you make all your rows like that, then the labels and input boxes will line up.

Comment: @Tatu Ulmanen: I tried this and it made both the labels and the text boxes line up individually which is what I was trying to do- so thank you! But now there is a lot of space between them? I tried resizing my window and I think it's because my screen is wide so I think it will correct itself depending on the size of the viewer's screen. What do you think?

Comment: @Ashley, by default, tables have a width of 100%, so the table stretches from left edge to the right edge of the window. And browsers usually split the cells 50/50, that's why there's a large gap. Set `width: auto;` to the table so it will take up only the space that is necessary. You can add `padding` to table cells to fine tune the gap.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That did work unfortunately I have to set it to 65% so it's going to have to do like it is I guess. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ashley, you can specify a width for the left column (the labels). In the first td of the first row, put a `style="width: 100px;"` etc. and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I posted an answer to your question over at Doctype: http://doctype.com/create-nested-table-html.
You should really look into using DIV's & CSS instead of Tables and Inline Styling for designing websites.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example of separating content from presentation. You have two main components on the page: A navigation menu (which is a list of links) and a contact form (which consists of a list of form elements). The HTML stands on its own and would display reasonably even without any styling.

First, styles are reset using [Yahoo!'s reset stylesheet](http://www.yahooapis.com/yui/3/cssreset/) to ensure that the starting point is the same regardless of browser-specific defaults. Then, specific styles are applied until the resulting display reasonably matches the requirements.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<link id="screen-reset" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.0.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">
<style type="text/css">
    html { background:#eef; font-size:18px;}
    body { background:#eee; margin:0 auto; width:95%;}
    #main { clear:both; }
    #hmenu { background:#fed; height:2em }
    #hmenu li { 
        background:#fed;
        display:block; 
        float:left; 
        padding:0 4px;
        border-left:solid 4px #dcb;
    }
    #hmenu a { 
        display:block; 
        font-family:sans-serif;
        font-size:1.5em;
        font-weight:bold;
        line-height:1.3333;
        text-decoration:none; 
    }
    form { padding:1em 0; }
    fieldset { 
        background:#fff; 
        border:solid 1px #222;
        padding:0.5em 0;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:90%; 
    }
    legend { 
        background:#eee;
        padding:0.1667em;
    }
    form li { 
        clear:both; 
        display:block;
        padding:1em 0;
    }
    form li label { 
        display:block; 
        float:left; 
        font-family:sans-serif;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding:0 0.25em 0 0;
        text-align:right; 
        width:35%; 
    }
    form li input[type="text"] { 
        display:block; 
        float:left; 
    }
    form input[type="submit"] {
        margin:0 0 0 35%;
    }
</style>

<title>Contact Form</title>

</head>

<body>

<div id="hmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="about.htm">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="mailto:cookiemaster@example.com">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="orderform.htm">Place an Order</a></li>
<li><a href="recipe.htm">Sample Recipe</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="main">
<form name="web-order-form" id="web-order-form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Information</legend>
        <ul>

            <li><label for="fname">First Name: </label>
            <input name="fname" id="fname" size="30" type="text"></li>

            <li><label for="lname">Last Name: </label>
            <input name="lname" id="lname" size="30" type="text"></li>

            <li><label for="address">Address: </label>
            <input name="address" id="address" size="30"
            type="text"></li>

            <li><label for="city">City: </label>
            <input name="city" id="city" size="35" type="text"></li>

            <li><label for="state">State: </label>
            <input name="state" id="state" size="3" type="text"></li>

            <li><label for="zip">Zip Code: </label>
            <input name="zip" id="zip" size="10" type="text"></li>

            <li><label for="country">Country: </label>
            <input name="country" id="country" size="10"
            type="text"></li>

            <li><input type="submit" name="submit-order" id="submit-order"
            value="Place Order"></li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the `input`s into `td`s of their own:

```
<tr>
    <td>First Name:</td>
    <td><input name="fname" id="fname" size="30" type="text"   /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Last Name:</td>
    <td><input name="lname" id="lname" size="30" type="text"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Address:</td>
    <td><input name="address" id="address" size="30" type="text"  /></td>
</tr>
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

One easy option might be using `flex` style in table cell

```
<td style="display:flex">
  <label>Flex</label>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</td>
```

It will show all elements in one row as long as there is enough space.